# Recursive Binary Tree Traversal Code Goes to Infinity

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to traverse a binary tree built with the input data from keyboard. Data is inserted to the binary tree successfully. I have a switch statement, where 'case 2' should traverse (and print) the binary tree with Inorder, Preorder and Postorder traversal algorithms using recursion respectively. However when 'case 2' is called, only the first data that should be printed regarding Inorder traversal is printed on screen; and it is also printed many times (infinite) where I need to stop the compiling operation. I would be more than happy if someone help me out with this one.

(RootPtr is the top -Level 0- node of the binary tree defined globally; and GetNode is basically an initializer function (using malloc) for type TreePtr pointers.)

Thank you all in advance.

This is the struct definition;

```
  typedef struct treeItem
{
    int data;
    struct treeItem *left;
    struct treeItem *right;

}Tree , *TreePtr;
```

These three are the traversing functions called respectively;

```
void inorder (TreePtr TemPtr)
{

    while(TemPtr != NULL)
    {
        inorder((*TemPtr).left);
        printf(" %d ", (*TemPtr).data);
        inorder((*TemPtr).right);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void preorder (TreePtr TemPtr)
{
    while(TemPtr != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d ", (*TemPtr).data);
        preorder((*TemPtr).left);
        preorder((*TemPtr).right);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void postorder (TreePtr TemPtr)
{
    while(TemPtr != NULL)
    {
        postorder((*TemPtr).left);
        postorder((*TemPtr).right);
        printf(" %d", (*TemPtr).data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This one is the related 'case' of the switch statement;

```
  case 2:
            TreePtr LocPtr;
            GetNode(&LocPtr);
            LocPtr = RootPtr;

            printf("\n");
            printf("Inorder traversal:");
            inorder(LocPtr);
            printf("Preorder traversal:");
            preorder(LocPtr);
            printf("Postorder traversal:");
            postorder(LocPtr);
            printf("\n");

            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a while loop inside your traversal functions. Recursivity will go in all nodes already.

```
void inorder (TreePtr TemPtr)
{
    if (TemPtr != NULL) {
        inorder((*TemPtr).left);
        printf(" %d ", (*TemPtr).data);
        inorder((*TemPtr).right);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

If you think about it, your `TemPtr` parameter isn't changing to `NULL` when you iterate in the loop. It would therefore be stuck in an infinite loop.

Explanation on tree traversal:

In your main, `case 2`, you call `inorder` with the root of the tree as parameter. Then we need to traverse the tree.

```
inorder(LocPtr);
```

In-order traversal is:

> go to left child ... visit current node ... go to right child

We need two things in a recursive function/method: a base case, and a recursive call.

Here, our base case is `if (TemPtr != NULL)`. When this condition is false, we know we have reached a leaf. If `TemPtr` indeed is a leaf, we don't go further to its children (which would throw errors).

But if `TemPtr` is not `NULL`, it means we are currently at a valid node. We must therefore follow the definition of in-order traversal (as stated previously).

We visit the left child:

```
inorder((*TemPtr).left); // equivalent to inorder(TemPtr->left);
```

we visit the current node:

```
printf(" %d ", (*TemPtr).data); // equivalent to printf (" %d ", TemPtr->data);
```

and we visit the right child:

```
inorder((*TemPtr).right); // equivalent to inorder(TemPtr->right);
```

When `inorder` is finished, the caller of `inorder` continues where it was. This process continues until `inorder(LocPtr)` finishes, and at this point you'll be back into the main, and your whole tree will have been traversed in-ordered.

The easiest way to visualize this is to draw the calls on a sheet of paper. Functions will stack on each other (`main` on the bottom), and are removed from the stack once they're finished.

Comment: Oh it makes sense now. Yes, I should remove 'while'. 

But how it will understand when to turn back or in other words when TemPtr reaches to the leaf node. 

e.g. Order of adding data to the tree: 9 6 12 8 2
For inorder traversal, 2 must be printed first. Then 6, then 8 etc. It must go through 9 and 6 to print 2, which is basically ( ( ( (TemPtr).left).left).left). So how it will know that going to left three times will be enough, and there is no 'left' at some point?

Comment: Thank you. I also tried removing while, it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the first line of the inorder function; which I usually get when I did not properly initialize pointers. But I did initialize same way I did for other functions (inserting node etc.)

Comment: The only thing I could not get is the condition TemPtr!=NULL. Since we cannot use it with while loop (because TemPtr will never be NULL), how it is useful when it is used in an if statement? TemPtr will never go NULL, therefore while loop goes infinity. TemPtr will never go NULL, the code in the if statement will always work and we cannot get out of the if statement. What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually now I see I could not explain my question properly. Let me ask this way. How the condition TemPtr!=NULL works with the if statement, when we say that the value TemPtr is not changing?

Comment: I reused your while condition, but usually I do `if TemPtr != nullptr`, which is self-explanatory. If the current node is a null pointer, then don't go further. When you build your add nodes, how do you handle leaves? When you call your constructor, you should set them equal to `nullptr` or `NULL`, otherwise they may have garbage value.

Comment: I also believe, as it can be seen from my original code, that I am also willing to use the condition TemPtr!=NULL to identify leaf nodes. But, why not while loop but if statement? Why the condition TemPtr!=NULL does not work with while loop?

Comment: Because `TemPtr` doesn't change with iterations of the loop. You're stuck with an infinite loop